# cron.daily not executing

Tags: cron

I am new to Linux.  I put a file in cron.daily to test, but it never got execute, access mod is 755 for the test file.

crontab file has the default entry of:
-*/15 * * * * root test -x /usr/lib/cron/run-crons && /usr/lib/cron/run-crons >/dev/null 2>&1

cron daemon is there. I can start a "at" job.

What do I miss ?

Comment: This file that you've placed is a bash script? And what does the logs say?

Comment: What does the actual cron script look like?

Answer (score 1):

Your script has `.sh` suffix doesn't it? ;)

**run-parts doesn't run anything with any suffix**. Files with suffix are silently ignored.

This is a documented but utterly stupid "feature":

`If neither the --lsbsysinit option nor the --regex option is given then
the names must consist entirely of upper and lower case  letters,  dig‐
its, underscores, and hyphens.`

Comment: Actually no.  The file name is test-it and it has one line in there just say "touch /tmp/x "

Comment: Try running run-crons manually and look in it's man page. See if it has a verbose flag or `strace` it.